# Expected one matching request, found 2 requests. How do I test for 2 requests

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-coverage

I am working on an Angular application and I am using Jasmine to test the application.

What I want is to test for two **similar** HTTP requests in one method such as, `ngOnInit()` .

I have an HTTP request that is called twice in `ngOnInit()` method and
write now the test case that I used throws an error like below:

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://localhost:8080/api/demoList", found 2 requests.

For example,

```
// method to test

ngOnInit() {
  this.httpGetRequest();
  // some other code
  this.httpGetRequest();
}

this.httpGetRequest() {
  this.httpClient.get(http://localhost:8080/api/getSomeList);
}

//test case for ngOnInit()

it('should do something', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit').and.callThrough();
  component.ngOnInit();

  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`http://localhost:8080/api/getSomeList`);
  expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
  req.flush(mockList);
});
```

How can I test for more than one request of similar URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`match`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController#match) method instead of `expectOne`. In your case it should return an array with 2 elements, one for each of the similar requests.